# upgrade python scripts from python 2 to python 3

Tags: python-3.x, upgrade, python-2.x

I have many scripts I need to upgrade from Python 2 to Python 3. I am familiar with some of the common changes to make, such as print a vs print(a) and iter[items|keys|etc]. I use 2to3 which seems to cover several of the changes needed, but misses others (runtime issues, bytes, unicode, etc). Is there a more complete script than 2to3, or something else that would cover most of the necessary changes?